# How would I got about proving the following: If $P_{n x n}$ matrix such that $P^{2}$ = P, then Col(P) = Null($I_{n}$ - P).

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Right now I am really stuck with this problem. I interpret this as asking me to prove:

Col(P) $\subseteq$ Null($I_{n}$ - P) and Null($I_{n}$ - P) $\subseteq$ Col(P)

My approach first begins with looking at Null($I_{n}$ - P) $\subseteq$ Col(P):

The solution to Null($I_{n}$ - P) = $\vec{0}$ or ($I_{n}$ - P)$\vec{x}$ = $\vec{0}$

($I_{n}$ - P)$\vec{x}$ = $\vec{0}$ , distributing $\vec{x}$

(*) $\vec{x}$ - P$\vec{x}$ = $\vec{0}$ , rearranging

(**) P$\vec{x}$ = $\vec{x}$ (curious does this not mean that P is actually the identity matrix $I_{n}$?)

Going back to (*)

$\vec{x}$ - P$\vec{x}$ = $\vec{0}$ , use what we found in (**)

$\vec{x}$ - $\vec{x}$ = $\vec{0}$

$\vec{0}$ = $\vec{0}$

This means that $\forall \vec{x}$ $\in$ $R^{n}$ is a solution to the Null($I_{n}$ - P)

Everything kinda falls apart here since I dont see how this is usefull in proving what it is I think I need to prove and I cant think of any other approach. If anyone has a solution or some pointers I would appreciate it.

p.s. This is my first time using Stack Exchange I apologize if I didnt use it appropiatly or if this is a poor question :(

Comment: $Px = x$ doesn't mean $P = I$. That's not how matrices work. Take for example $2×2$ matrix with all entries equal to $1/2$ and take $x = (1, 1)$

Answer (score 1):

The steps in the first part of your proof look OK to me. You can't use the result $Px = x$ in the other direction of the proof, since you used the assumption that $x \in \text{null}(I_n - P)$ to derive this. This is the statement you want to show for the other direction. This also does not mean that $P$ is the identity matrix on $\mathbb R^n$, only that $P$ is the identity map when **restricted to** $\text{null}(I - P)$.

Let's show $\text{col}(P) \subseteq \text{null}(I_n - P)$. Let $v \in \text{col}(P)$. Then there exists some $w \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $v = Pw$. Note that $Pv = P^2 w = Pw = v$, since $P^2 = P$. Hence, $v - Pv = 0$ so that $(I_n - P)v = 0$. Therefore, $v \in \text{null}(I_n - P)$.